# Will Apple include Mac mini 2014 late in his next OS upgrade after Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, mac-mini

Catalina is supporting Mac mini late 2014 models. But I want to know about the next os upgrade. Will Apple include Mac mini late 2014 in his next upgrade?

And one more thing is: for how many year will I get an upgrade of the latest macOS for my Mac mini late 2014.

I know it's very hard to say about it but then also any guesses.

Comment: Flag this for opening once a new OS is released so we can answer authoritatively and not speculate.

Comment: @bmike okay sure

Answer (score 3):

If I take the reference of the following screenshot for all old models of Apple, your macMini should last for a couple of years more. After 8 years also, late 2012 still supports Catalina.

[image]

In nutshell, if there are no any major hardware changes in upcoming macOS, I guess your 2014 will definitely support the next version of macOS.

Comment: For anyone coming later, both macOS Big Sur and macOS Monterey support late 2014 Mac mini.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I have read including [this article](https://lowendmac.com/2013/how-long-do-apple-support-your-mac/) and experienced over the last few years, Apple computers get OS updates until they are 5 to 7 years old (as measured based on their model years).

So this means Apple computers usually get OS updates until they become vintage as defined by Apple. Apple says it considers products that have not been manufactured for more than 5 and less than 7 years ago as vintage. Anything that has not been manufactured for more than 7 years is considered to be obsolete by Apple. See [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624) for the current list of Apple products considered as vintage or obsolete by Apple.

Based on those definitions and the current lists for vintage and obsolete products, it looks to me like the Mac mini 2014 may get an OS update at least for another year.

Comment: According to this list at https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/index-macmini.html, Apple has continued manufacturing the Mac mini 2014 up until 2018. So it seems like this product will go vintage earliest by 2023. So there is a good case that it might get an OS update even in 2022

Answer (score -3):

It's impossible to say what Apple's future plans might be. However, you can of course continue to use a Mac perfectly well without upgrading.

But: if I still had a 2014 Mini, I'd be saving up for a better Mac. ;-)